# Can anyone please identify this plant? It has fern like leaves and purpleish/brown stems which seem to root when they lay on soil

Tags: identification

Fern like leaves and long stems that seem to root themselves as they lay on soil.  Also will have beautiful flowers as per the person who gave me the cutting.  Writing from Central California.

---

Fern like foliage with purple/brown stems and will have flowers.

Comment: Please add a photo. BTW: Welcome to SE

Comment: Welcome Marie!! Could you please post a picture of your plant for us to look at? We'd like to see the leaves, and the flowers too, but it you don't have flowers yet, could you describe them a bit? You can post pictures by pressing on the icon along the top row of your question that looks like a box with a mountain in it! If you have any trouble, please leave a comment here and we'll help you!